# How do I indent the text after the enumerate numbers?

Tags: enumerate

So I want to indent the bottom portion of the text under the number to fit the text. How do I do it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{enumerate}
{\setlength\itemindent{25pt} \item Sản phẩm nông, lâm, ngư nghiệp đóng góp một phần không nhỏ vào cơ cấu sản phẩm trong nước}
{\setlength\itemindent{25pt} \item Ngành nông, lâm, ngư nghiệp sản xuất và cung cấp lương thực, thực phẩm cho tiêu dùng trong nước, cung cấp nguyên liệu cho ngành công nghiệp chế biến}
{\setlength\itemindent{25pt} \item Ngành nông, lâm, ngư nghiệp có vai trò quan trọng trong sản xuất hàng hóa xuất khẩu}
{\setlength\itemindent{25pt} \item Hoạt động nông, lâm, ngư nghiệp còn chiếm trên 50\% tổng số lao động tham gia vào các ngành kinh tế}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Please clarify from where the indentation should be measured: From the numbers of the enumerated list, or from the first word in each list item (e.g., `Sản`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). It provides commands to customize easily the layout of list environments using a key-value syntax. In the following example, you can adjust the indentation of the list using the keyword `labelindent`. The details are all in the documentation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Sản phẩm nông, lâm, ngư nghiệp đóng góp một phần không nhỏ vào cơ cấu sản phẩm trong nước
    \item Ngành nông, lâm, ngư nghiệp sản xuất và cung cấp lương thực, thực phẩm cho tiêu dùng trong nước, cung cấp nguyên liệu cho ngành công nghiệp chế biến
    \item Ngành nông, lâm, ngư nghiệp có vai trò quan trọng trong sản xuất hàng hóa xuất khẩu
    \item Hoạt động nông, lâm, ngư nghiệp còn chiếm trên 50\% tổng số lao động tham gia vào các ngành kinh tế
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```